# Can I play a 'not available for Linux' game on Steam using Wine or PlayOnLinux?

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I bought a games bundle which has games that are both available and not available for Linux. I understand that to play the available games for Linux I only have to download Steam and voilà. But is it possible to play the games that are 'not available for Linux' by installing steam on PlayOnLinux or Wine and then installing the game with steam?
I got Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, you could download steam for windows using wine then download the games, or if you had enough ram you could use virtualbox with a windows os. and if you're a hardcore gamer you could download windows alongside ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I'll download the windows version and write here if it works or not.

Comment: just remembered if you download the windows steam for wine you'll have to install the missing fonts or you'll wont be able to see text and it's extremely slow the best thing to do is to install windows alongside ubuntu

Comment: The missing fonts were automatically installed with Steam, so there was no need to manually do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Ubuntu question, but primarily Wine. See their site https://appdb.winehq.org/. There you can see list of Windows applications and their Wine tests (for different versions, distributions and etc). They have good rank and description (usually) for wine abilities for running different applications or workarounds to run something using Wine.

Comment: I thought of going there but I already have an account here and people usually answer pretty fast here.

Comment: It's just a note, because your question is about range of games/applications, askubuntu don't have description of wide range, but wine appdb does. Well, when you asking for Steam games - wine appdb have description for many games steam versions too.

Comment: just search your game in winedb and you'll see what you can do using wine. If it's helpfull for you please upvote answer

Comment: @Rin007 is there any correct answer for you? Please mark correct answer as accepted or upvote if you find it usefull.